# I have saved my secret key by encrypting it to hash using salt. How do i use this hash password to to create amazons3client?

Tags: amazon-s3, knox-amazon-s3-client

I have saved my secret key by encrypting it to hash using salt. How do i use this hash password to to create AmazonS3Client ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't think you can. Why did you hash the Secret Key?

Comment: The Secret Key does get hashed as part of the [Signature Version 4 signing process](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html), but I think you will need your non-hashed Secret Key in order to make the Signature.